# PayPal: Sandbox UI is different from "real" UI?

Tags: paypal, sandbox

As I've been integrating with PayPal, I've noticed that their sandbox UI is very different from their real UI.

When I set my button to post to `sandbox.paypal.com`, I get something like this:
[image]

But when I post to `paypal.com` from a browser that has never visited PayPal before, I get this:
[image]

Is there any way to setup the sandbox so its interface will be closer to the "real" PayPal's interface?

Comment: Superuser? Or has that web-api one made it into beta?

Comment: I would *think* this is programming related; the only people who would know the answer are developers who have had to interface with the PayPal API…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen it, but perhaps that's a [New UI](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/release_notes/platformrn/blog/2010/06/21/bulletin-paypal-developer-pre-release-notes--june-2010)?  The quote below is about all I've been able to find out about it though.

> The Adaptive Payments consumer
>   experience will be upgraded to the **new
>   PayPal payment flow design being
>   rolled out across all PayPal products**.
>   The new UI will show the merchant's
>   business name instead of their email
>   address and will have a split slider
>   showing the payment breakdown on the
>   left and the login/approval on the
>   right.

Answer (score 1):

David seems to be right — they are rolling out a new UI on the real site, but I guess the sandbox hasn't gotten it yet.

Also, clearing all my `*sandbox.paypal.com` cookies gives me a "pay with credit card" screen instead of the "log into PayPal" screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with new paypal interface, also mentioned in developer community forum on their website. many of the users are having problem since 1 month, and paypal is still working on it to resolve the issue.

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi